# open edx styles of cms doesn't work

Tags: openedx

CSS doesn't work in cms (open edx). I tried to compile JS and CSS, but it gave no results. Server reboot didn't help me. This is my error in log:

```
[__init__.py:42] - staticfiles_storage couldn't find path css/cms-style-vendor-tinymce-content.css: The file 'css/cms-style-vendor-tinymce-content.css' could not be found with <cms.lib.django_require.staticstorage.OptimizedCachedRequireJsStorage object at 0x8c1b950>.
[__init__.py:42] - staticfiles_storage couldn't find path css/cms-style-vendor.css: The file 'css/cms-style-vendor.css' could not be found with <cms.lib.django_require.staticstorage.OptimizedCachedRequireJsStorage object at 0x8c1b950>.
[__init__.py:42] - staticfiles_storage couldn't find path css/studio-main.css: The file 'css/studio-main.css' could not be found with <cms.lib.django_require.staticstorage.OptimizedCachedRequireJsStorage object at 0x8c1b950>.
[shortcuts.py:56] - Cannot find corresponding link for name: ROOT
[shortcuts.py:56] - Cannot find corresponding link for name: TOS
[shortcuts.py:56] - Cannot find corresponding link for name: PRIVACY
```

=================================================================

[frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4291555/frank) helped me to solve my problem

```
sudo -H -u edxapp bash
source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
paver update_assets lms --settings=aws

python manage.py cms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py lms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput

sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp:
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:
```

Comment: have you done `collectstatic` ?

Comment: I did this:
sudo -H -u edxapp bash
source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
paver update_assets lms --settings=aws

Comment: normally update_assets will do the collectstatic, but still, try this ,
./manage.py cms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput
./manage.py lms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput

Comment: should I use this command: paver update_assets lms ?

Comment: no, after these commands, run collectstatic,  sudo -H -u edxapp bash source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform

Comment: thanks a lot! your advices help me

Comment: ok, for the sake of stackoverflow i'll post it as answer !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You Should run collectstatic after compiling your static assets.

```
    sudo -H -u edxapp bash

    source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env

    cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform

    python manage.py cms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput

    python manage.py lms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -H -u edxapp bash
source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
paver update_assets lms --settings=aws

python manage.py cms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py lms --settings=aws collectstatic --noinput

sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp:
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:
```